# Simon Says C# console, getting runtime error

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to solve this problem https://open.kattis.com/problems/simon on open.kattis.com and I have this piece of code and it does exactly what it is supposed to, if the string starts with simon says then it the rest of the string is outputed, and if it doesn't start with simon says then output a blank line.

```
using System;

namespace Tester
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int lines = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] inputs = new string[lines];
            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            {
                inputs[i] = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (inputs[i].StartsWith("simon says"))
                    inputs[i] = inputs[i].Substring(10);
                else
                    inputs[i] = "";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(inputs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
4
simon says write a program
print some output
simon whispers do not stress
simon says get balloons
```

Output:

```
write a program


get balloons
```

The testcase works fine in VS. No exceptions there.
But when I submit it for testing, I get Runtime Error. Any ideas what it could be caused by? The platform says that it is an uncaught exception, but does not specify what exception

Edit: So now I have wrong answer although the output is correct when testing in VS.

Edit: Test case works in kattis.com but not their hidden test case

Comment: Run it in debug mode from Visual Studio and you will see. Or catch the exception and log it. Then if you want to see closely what could cause it, set a breakpoint and debug it step by step.

Comment: check and make sure the string is long enough for the 2 substrings you have in your code

Comment: ToInt32 can cause it, Substring...

Comment: @Spawn in what way? :)

Answer (score 5):

Change your `if` statement to `if (inputs[i].StartsWith("simon says"))`. It doesn't depend on the string's length.

Comment: Thx! better way than my mine at least :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of bugs in the code. The first thing to remember when posting questions about code not working is to tell us which line is blowing up, what (if any) inputs you've given the application and (most importantly) what exception you are getting.

int lines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// will fail when input isn't numeric

if (inputs[i].Substring(0, 10) == "simon says")

//will fail when input is less than 10 characters

inputs[i] = inputs[i].Substring(11);

//You should use 10, not 11 since the next input after "simon says" could be in the 10th index position.
   //will fail if user only types "simon says" (no 12th character)

Comment: I am not getting an exception in VS but when I submit the assignment for testing.

Comment: You're being fed pathological test cases: non-numbers in the first line, short lines, lines starting with spaces.  Read this. http://www.sempf.net/post/On-Testing1.aspx

Comment: @Yaner What are you submitting the assignment for testing to?  We don't know what you mean by this. What system is giving you an exception and what exception are you getting?  We can't help if you don't provide details.

Comment: @user1739635 it's for open.kattis.com. Now when I changed to substring(10) I dont get runtime error, but now I get "Wrong Answer". About the exception, it just said "Uncaught Exception" altough the test case works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int testCases = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var print = new List<string>();

        while (testCases-- > 0)
        {
            var line = Console.ReadLine();
            print.Add(line.StartsWith("simon says ") ? line.Remove(0, 11) : "");
        }

        foreach (var simonSaid in print)
            Console.WriteLine(simonSaid);
    }
```

Comment: that totally worked! thx for the solution, and yes I should've solved it myself... still though, many thx :)